# include shortcode values in Thickbox form

Tags: jquery, shortcode, thickbox

I have a shortcode that is built using a Thickbox form with various inputs that return the values. This works fine. However, I would like the existing values (if present) to re-populate the form if the user opens it again.

**Here is an example of my shortcode:**

`[schema type="person" name="Andrew Norcross" description="I make interwebs" ]`

**I have a working jQuery match function to find the shortcode if it exists:**

`var code = $('div#wp-content-editor-container textarea').text().match(/\[schema(.*)\]/g);`

the code above does get the entire shortcode as a string, but I'm at a loss for how to process it efficiently to get the values I want.

**so what I want to accomplish:**

1. check for a specific part inside the shortcode data (i.e. name="Andrew Norcross")
2. get the value inside the quotes and insert it into the field on the form

I've tried a few ways but nothing seems to function as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
var code = $('div#wp-content-editor-container textarea').text().match(/\[(schema.*)\]/);
code = '<' + code[1] + '>';
alert($(code).attr('description'));​​​​
```

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using jQuery's .data() function. Because its a shortcode, you can't really store values from the form into the 's data attributes and retrieve them that way, storing them with the .data() function seems like your best bet.

http://api.jquery.com/data/